# Web API Multiple Actions were found that match this request, if called without parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've got a problem using ASP.NET WebAPI Controller. What i try to build is a controller which contains two actions that can be called by a http-get. What i have so far:

```
[HttpGet]
public IList<Model> Get()
{
    ...
}
[HttpGet]
public IList<Model> GetAllWorkshops()
{
    ...
}
```

I also edited my RouteConfig.cs to the following:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "API Default With ID",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "API Default",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The strange behaviour is that if i call : http://localhost:1536/Api/Workshop/Get or localhost:1536/Api/Workshop/GetAllWorkshops, i get the exception that multiple actions were found that match this request. But if i call localhost:1536/Api/Workshop/Get/1 or localhost:1536/Api/Workshop/GetAllWorkshops/1 it was works perfectly. So i think that the route with the id works. But why do the other two requests throw these exceptions?

I tried almost every imaginable route. It would be great if you find my mistakes!

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should not need the route in the middle, the first and second one are the same, and i dont see your actions that takes in the ID in your controller!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because route named "API Default With ID" has `id` as optional, so `/api/workshop/get` matched both the first and second route, hence the error.

To fix this error, you can remove second route because it is just a subset of the first route template.

However, it is better to use new [Attribute Routing introduced in Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), it is by far more maintainable and easy to understand than using old-style mapping.

If you use attribute mapping, your class will look like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/workshop")]
public class WorkshopController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Get")]
    public IList<Model> Get()
    {
        ...
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetAllWorkshops")]
    public IList<Model> GetAllWorkshops()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Very clear and concise.